# SQL Server - Set based method for incrementing every N records

Tags: sql-server, increment

Using SQL Server 2008

I am working on a method for merging multiple invoices into a single invoice. I can leverage our existing claim adjustment stored procedures if, instead of supplying an invoice ID, I supply a batch ID with which multiple invoices will be associated.

The specifics of this problem allow some automation: The invoices to be grouped will always be  adjacent in their table, and the group size is constant within each set of batches.

My question: Does T-SQL provide a set-based (i.e. not a loop) method for auto-incrementing an "ID" column every N records?

I know a non-set based method would be to use a cursor with a counter that increments every time the ID % N equals 0. See the following sample for a field to be incremented every two records:

```
    CREATE TABLE #BatchInvnums (id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, invnum INT, batchID INT)

    INSERT INTO #BatchInvnums (invnum)
    VALUES (178),(543),(724),(809),(164),(276)

    DECLARE @CurrentID INT,  @CurrentInvnum INT, @Counter INT = 0

    DECLARE CurBatchIDSetter CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY FOR
    SELECT ID, invnum
    FROM #BatchInvnums
    ORDER BY ID

    OPEN CurBatchIDSetter
    FETCH NEXT FROM CurBatchIDSetter INTO @CurrentID, @CurrentInvnum

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE #BatchInvnums
        SET batchID = @Counter
        WHERE invnum = @CurrentInvnum

        IF @CurrentID % 2 = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
        END
        FETCH NEXT FROM CurBatchIDSetter INTO @CurrentID, @CurrentInvnum
    END

    CLOSE CurBatchIDSetter
    DEALLOCATE CurBatchIDSetter
```

Again, the above is what I would rather not do. I'd like to use either a single update statement or, better yet, some property applied on table creation in order to achieve this effect. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `row_number()` is probably the route to the solution

```
update #BatchInvnums
set batchID = rn
from
    #BatchInvnums
        inner join
        (select id,
                (ROW_NUMBER()over(order by id)-1) / 2 rn 
         from #BatchInvnums) v
        on v.id = #batchinvnums.id
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using [ROW_NUMBER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) ( as an integer, and then integer division).

Something like

```
SELECT *,
(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) - 1)/ 2 RowID
FROM TADA
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e9d61/8)

This will also allow you to determine the partitioning, and ordering of the row number.